# exclude part of page from having css applied?

Tags: html, css

I have been tasked with making some updates to an existing web control and placing it on an existing web page. The web control uses a lot of hard coded formatting to make it look "pretty", and the web page uses CSS to override just about every visual element you could imaging. So when the control is placed on the page it looks REALLY bad. Its basically unusable and I'm not sure what the best approach is to fix it.

Is there a way to clear CSS from, for example, all elements which are part of a specified DIV, or some way to prevent the main css from being applied to these components?

Comment: you could apply a reset style sheet to the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a [CSS reset stylesheet](http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssreset/reset-context-min.css) (just add the class `yui3-cssreset` to your element).

The only problem, though, is that it only normalizes little nuances between browsers, and isn't made for completely killing all stylesheets.

You *could*, however, edit in code to reset the `background`, `font`, `border`, etc.

Comment: Reset style sheets do not what the question asks for. They just set properties to some values that someone chose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the not pseudo selector like:

> :not(#idname) {
>       Properties... }

But that won't work everywhere without a JS shim.